# How to show comaparison data in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two mobile phones data & i need to show a comparison between those two phone models on single screen. Is there any control that could do this kind of thing.?

I thought about Tabs but they r not very handy to user..

Plz suggest me something... :D

Comment: What kind of question is this? I didn't get exactly what you means by this question.

Comment: That depends on so many things. Can you add more details? Is it possible to make all those data fit in one screen (without loosing clarity)?  Otherwise, instead of tabs use a ViewPager (or as they call it now, SlidingTabs) to let the user swipe between those two columns.
By the way, this is not really a programming question but a UI/UX question.

Comment: @Amokrane Chentir, Yes its a UI question.. SlidingTabs will be very problematic for user..

Comment: @MicroEyes FYI, you should ask this on http://ux.stackexchange.com/, this is where it belongs. And you will get better answers there!

Answer (score 0):

Please Try with ListView with two columns

Comment: i know this  thing, in that case i don't have only 2 cols, they r 3. One is for Spec type(processor, Memory, etc.) other two columns for Phone Models. They will take more space width wise..

Answer (score 0):

Use a TableLayout, you can create columns and rows.
[Table Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html)